# How to modify the base class of the class builded by "yiic migrate create XXX"?

Tags: yii

All

I am using "yiic migrate" to setup my database, 
But I got a problem, 
for example, 
$ ./yiic migrate create create_table_user

then, I got a class like this :

```
class m130918_015910_create_table_weddings extends CDbMigration
{
    // something else 
}
```

But I want it to be like this :

```
class m130918_015910_create_table_weddings extends migration_create_table
{
    // something else 
}
```

Is there any idea to do this ?

Oh, BTW, I searched the handbook, but nothing I got...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the page on the Yii guide about migrations, you can adjust the template file used with a `templateFile` flag on the command line:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration#customizing-migration-command

Think that's what you need ...